# What would happen if init was deleted?

Tags: kernel, init

Just a theoretical question...

But what would happen if `init` (in `/sbin/init`) would be removed?

Comment: Don't try ln `-L` -- it won't work. `cp /proc/fd/1/exe /sbin/init && chmod 755 /sbin/init` works though. Using APT to re-install upstart is not as obvious as `dpkg`, as it won't know it's gone by default. "Package upstart is already at the current version." You could `dpkg --force-depends --force-remove-essential -r upstart` first.

Comment: `apt-get install --reinstall upstart`. Also, I don't have `/proc/fd` directory. And I just checked, `ln -L /proc/1/exe /tmp/init` works with `/sbin/init` renamed to `/sbin/init.bak`, i.e. I can read without a problem `/tmp/init` after this.

Comment: @muru OK. I'll add a tag synonym then.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The boot loader will load the kernel, the kernel would attempt to run init, not find it and panic.

The way out of it is to reboot, edit the boot parameters, add `init=/bin/bash` and boot that way. The kernel will use bash as init. This will give you a chance to run commands and fix the system.

**Correction**
Apparently the kernel (file [init/main.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c?v=3.13#L874)) does:

```
if (!try_to_run_init_process("/sbin/init") ||
    !try_to_run_init_process("/etc/init") ||
    !try_to_run_init_process("/bin/init") ||
    !try_to_run_init_process("/bin/sh"))
        return 0;

panic("No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. "
      "See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.");
```

So it would find /bin/sh (which is a link to dash) and that will give you a shell and a chance to fix it without using the `init=/bin/bash` boot parameter.

Comment: Great answer. Didn't know that kernel searches for something more than `/sbin/init`.

Comment: And if there is no `/bin/sh` file? Or `/bin/bash` or `/bin/dash` etc? Not sure how you could delete all of these at the same time, but what would happen, theoretically?

Comment: Well, then you would see the kernel panic, the part of the answer above the **Correction** line. But don't do that on a system you need. Seriously, don't. If you want to experiment (and it is a good exercise) create a Virtualbox VM, break it and try to fix it. BTW the answer by 200_success is not bad either.

Answer (score 12):

Nothing happens, until you try to reboot.  As long as the system is running, and you don't try to switch runlevels by running `/sbin/init` *n*, you wouldn't even realize it was gone.

Actually, deletion of `/sbin/init` is undoable if you realize the mistake early and stay calm.  System administrators have [recovered from much nastier "lobotomies"](http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/recovery.html) while keeping the operating system running.

One way to recover from the deletion of `/sbin/init` is to reinstall the `upstart` package using APT.

The macho way to recover is to use only the resources on the machine itself.  One factor in your favour is that `/sbin/init` is always running.  Therefore, when you run `rm /sbin/init`, the file is merely unlinked from the filesystem.  The inode and file contents remain on disk and in memory until PID 1 exits.  You merely need to re-create  `/sbin/init` from the appropriate inode.

The [easiest way](https://serverfault.com/a/238431/15051) to accomplish that is:

```
# cp /proc/1/exe /sbin/init
# chmod 755 /sbin/init
```