# Is it possible to uninstall sh?

Tags: command-line, uninstall, sh

This may sound silly but I want to uninstall sh (for research purposes) and replace it with my own shell. Is this actually possible?

Many scripts and programs seem to have it hardcoded in, so I'm in doubt as to its viability.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is a symlink, so you could just change it to point to your own shell instead. Beware that you might seriously break things if your own shell doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @JonasCz Yeah. He might want to test in a VM with snapshots.

Comment: Doing it this way is a *very bad idea*. I recommend using the `chsh` command, `chsh -s /path/to/shell`.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by `research purposes` ? If you have no idea what you're doing, you might seriously break your system, and then no lol-cats for you no more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **⚠️ *WARNING! PLEASE READ BEFORE RUNNING ANY COMMANDS!* ⚠️**
>
> This answer is *only* provided for research and to further knowledge of Ubuntu Linux. Running any commands in this answer may very well destroy your system entirely. Make sure you're in a VM or a backup. I am not responsible if you break your system.

The command `sh` is provided by `dash`, by way of a symlink:

```
$ ll /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jun  1 08:33 /bin/sh -> dash*

$ which sh
/bin/sh

$ dpkg -S /bin/dash
dash: /bin/dash

$ dpkg -S /bin/sh
diversion by dash from: /bin/sh
diversion by dash to: /bin/sh.distrib
dash: /bin/sh
```

To remove it, run the below command:

```
sudo apt remove dash
```

APT will kick you back with the following error message:

```
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
```

If you are really willing to destroy your system, type that in and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Ubuntu will then uninstall `bash`, `lightdm`, and the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package (as well as all packages that depend on those three), because they all have a dependency on `dash`. Unless your current shell works perfectly, your system will be unusable after you kill the last instance of `bash` or `dash`.

If you actually follow through with this command, the only way to restore the proper files is to boot into a Live CD and re-install the packages through a `chroot`ed recovery session.

If you're *really* lucky, you might still be able to repair your system live by re-installing the packages, provided you still have a root shell open. [Systems have recovered from worse](http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/recovery.html) before, but luck really needs to be on your side for that.

---

Instead, I would suggest you re-make the `/bin/sh` symlink to point to your shell. In that case, you can just restore back to `dash` if something goes really really wrong. Do this by running these commands:

```
sudo -s
cd /bin
rm sh
ln -s /path/to/your/shell sh
chmod 777 sh
```

Restore back to `dash` by repeating these steps, but specifying `dash` instead of your own shell. Or just run `sudo apt install --reinstall dash`. You might need to [specify a custom `init`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475517/what-would-happen-if-init-was-deleted) to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I would install your own shell alongside SH. Uninstalling SH is a VERY bad idea, as numerous programs and scripts rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

Fast forward a few years, and yes, `sh` can be uninstalled and made to work, but only in single-application scenarios, such as dedicated docker containers, not in universal multi-application systems.

For instance it has been used by Google in their [distroless containers](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless). Some apps can be *copied* there (having been installed in a more complete system, e.g. Debian at an earlier stage, using a two-stage docker build), complete with all their shared dependencies identified using `ldd` (as long as they do not depend on `*sh` or `xterm`).